# Multiple insert in one form, for one-to-many relations in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, dom

Hi I am trying to experiment on how to enter multiple data in one form.

The case study that I use here is about how to enter multiple serial numbers of goods where they have the same item_id, I want to make the input in the same form and the serial number that I can enter for the same item id is unlimited or according to the number of limits max post data.

thank you for

W3school-HTML DOM Input Text Object https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp

pavlen & Corez64 https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/insert-array-data-with-eloquent

Comment: Are you mean the one ID repeat multiple time?

Answer (score 1):

CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.2/slimselect.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.26.2/slimselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

Body

```
<div class="form-group container-fluid" >

<form method="post" action="{{ url('/main/serialadd')}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{Session::get('userData')['name']}}" class="form-control">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="h3">Select barang</label>
    <select id="single" name="idbarang" >
        @foreach($barang as $row)
         <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->namabarang}} {{$row->type}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>

    {{-- input area --}}
    <div class="form-group" id="inputarea"></div>
    {{-- end area --}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add Serial</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeinput()">Remove</button>
    </div>


    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add Serial</button>


</form>
</div>
```

Script

```
{{-- add --}}
<script>
        var i = 0;
        function myFunction() {
          i++;
          var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
          x.setAttribute("id", "thisinput" + i);
          x.setAttribute("type", "text");
          x.setAttribute("placeholder", "Input the serial number");
          x.setAttribute("value", "");
          x.setAttribute("name", "serial[]");
          x.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
          document.getElementById("inputarea").appendChild(x);

        }
</script>

{{-- remove --}}
<script>
    function removeinput() {
  var select = document.getElementById('inputarea');
  select.removeChild(select.lastChild);
}
</script>

{{-- slim-select --}}
<script>
    new SlimSelect({
        select: '#single'
})
</script>
```

Controller

```
$status = "new";
        $data = [];//menampung array dari multiple insert
        foreach($request->serial as $key) {
            $data = [
                'serial' => $key,
                'idbarang' => $request->idbarang,
                'status' => $status,
                'created_at'=> Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at'=> Carbon::now(),
                'created_by' =>$request->user];
            model::insert($data);
        }
            dd($data);
        }
```